# How to make the background picture change with movement of the window in Qt/c++?

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

Is it possible to make the background (one picture) change with the movement of the window (move the coordinates of the SAME picture) in Qt?

I tried setting Stylesheets but it did not work.

This is what I want to achieve [Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqBOr.png) so for example, if I move the window a little to the left instead of having "age of window" I should get "ound image of window"

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Not sure but it sounds as if you want the parent widget to have the image as a background with the child having a completely transparent background, no?  **Edit:** Your latest update seems to confirm that.

Comment: @G.M. I don't want a transparent window. It's quite similar to what I want but instead of seeing what's under the window I want to change it to a picture. I hope you get what I mean. I also added a picture and description so check them

Comment: @G.M. sorry to bother you. but do you know how to achieve it? and thank you

Comment: Maybe you can use a `QPainter` to draw background and calculate the position of top left when window moving.

Comment: Any succes? I have some ideas...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but I haven't found anything. @Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here my solution: By reimplementing the `paintEvent` and `moveEvent`(to repaint on movement) you can reach your goal.

Here is my reimplementation of `QWidget::paintEvent`:

```cpp
void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e) {
    QMainWindow::paintEvent(e);

    QPainter painter(this);

    auto window = pos();

    painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, _pixmapBg, window.x(), window.y(), 0, 0);
}
```

In the `moveEvent` we call `repaint` so `paintEvent` gets called:

```cpp
void MainWindow::moveEvent(QMoveEvent *e) {
    repaint();

    QMainWindow::moveEvent(e);
}
```

Here the full code in a github [repo](https://github.com/tim-gromeyer/stackoverflow/tree/make-background-move-dynamically).

I hope it helps even tought it's a bit laggy. And a happy new year!